# How do I get the memory usage of a process?

Tags: macos, memory

I have tried:

1. `ps -e -o pid,rss,vsz | grep "$pid"` but both of rss and vsz are wildly different to the number in activity monitor.
2. `top -l 1 | grep "$pid"` this memory is the same as the number in activity monitor, but when the number is greater than 10GB it loss precision and only show integral parts.
3. `vmmap --summary "$pid" | grep "Physical footprint:"` this is accurate but when the command runs the whole system lagged for a split second.

Comment: Do you need this in a form that a script can process, or is it for general curiosity, or some other reason?

Comment: I am debugging a memory leak issue. I want to record the memory usage of a process every minute.

Answer (score 1):

RSS: Activity Monitor has additional columns you can show. In particular "Real Memory" is the same as RSS.

VSZ: Click the Info button in Activity Monitor. This shows more details about the process, including Virtual Memory Size (as well as Real Memory Size).

`top`: I agree with your comment, and don't find `top` useful on macOS.

`vmmap`: This is not suitable for general use - it is a command for the developer and/or memory specialist.  The delay on my Mac is minimal.

Personally I have only ever used `vmmap` when monitoring the macOS bug of  about 2 years ago which created a kernel memory leak in VMware.

Regarding your headline question:

- Activity Monitor (with additional columns) is, for most of us, a good way of seeing a processes memory usage. `ps` is not needed unless you want to script something.
- `top` is of little value on macOS (opinion).
- `vmmap` is for developers and memory specialists.